# Algorithm for detecting a double gutter in poker

Tags: algorithm

A double gutter in poker is when you have 2 gut shots to a straight.

For example, if the board is 268 and you have 45, a 3 (23456) or a 7 (45678) will complete a straight for you.

Given board[] and hand[], what's an efficient algorithm for returning true if you have a double gutter and false if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an algorithm that can do this with bit vectors.

First, create a bit vector of 14 bits, say `cards` (to include low and high ace) and set each bit for each element in `hand[]` and `board[]`.

Next, generate 5 pairs of masks `(mask, gutter)` for the first element in `hand[]` such that `((cards & mask) ^ gutter)==0` if you have a double gutter. E.g., if one of your cards is `7`, the `(mask, gutter)` pairs would be (assuming MSB->LSB order):

```
01111111000000, 01011101000000
00000001111111, 00000001011101
00000111111100, 00000101110100
00001111111000, 00001011101000
00011111110000, 00010111010000
```

I.e., you have 2 double gutters with 7 on either end and 3 with 7 in the middle.

Now, calculate `((cards & mask) ^ gutter)` for each of the 5 pairs. If any is `0` you have a double gutter.

EDIT: turns out you only need to test 5 masks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

1. Make a bool array (or bit field) for every card value
2. For every card in board[] and hand[], set the corresponding entry to true
3. Check all possibilities for a straight; since you don't care about colors, options are very limited (i.e. 23456, 34567 etc.) - if exactly one card is missing from a possible straight, add it to a set (which cannot contain duplicates).
4. Return true iff the set contains exactly 2 entries.

Alternatively, do one experiment for any value not yet on the board, checking if you have a straight if you add that value and count the ones for which this happens.

All the algorithms are constant time (since the entire situation is limited), and they don't take a really large effort.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach using bit-wise operations :

```
vec = 0
```

map `hand[]` and `board[]` to bits of the number `vec`, then

```
gutter = 0
for i = 0 to 10
    x = (vec & 0x1f) ^ 0x1f
    if x one of 1,2,4,8,16
        gutter++
        if gutter >= 2
            return true
    vec = vec >> 1
return false
```